# Displaying RGB numbers of an image

Tags: java, image, rgb, pixel

I need to display all of the RGB numbers for each pixel in a chosen picture, with each number separated by a space, and use println (break) after every row of the picture. I've figured out and written the code to return all of the RGB numbers, but I don't know how to break after each row. Here is my code so far..

```
public void getColor()
{
  System.out.println("This picture's dimensions are: "+this.getWidth()+" by "+this.getHeight());
   for (int row=0; row < this.getHeight(); row++) // gives the number of rows
   {
     for (int col=0; col < this.getWidth(); col++)// gives the number of columns
     {
       Pixel pix = this.getPixel(col,row);        
       System.out.print(pix.getRed()+" "+pix.getGreen()+" "+pix.getBlue()+" ");
     } // end of inner loop
   }// end of outer loop
} // end of method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to put the line break outside of the innermost for loop because you want it to run after each row is done.

```
public void getColor()
{
  System.out.println("This picture's dimensions are: "+this.getWidth()+" by "+this.getHeight());
   for (int row=0; row < this.getHeight(); row++) // gives the number of rows
   {

     for (int col=0; col < this.getWidth(); col++)// gives the number of columns
     {
       Pixel pix = this.getPixel(col,row);        
       System.out.print(pix.getRed()+" "+pix.getGreen()+" "+pix.getBlue()+" ");
     } // end of inner loop

    //After this ^^^ for loop runs, you've gone over the whole row.
    System.out.println();
   }// end of outer loop
} // end of method
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line break to the end of every line by inserting a print statement between the inner and outer loops.

```
public void getColor()
{
  System.out.println("This picture's dimensions are: "+this.getWidth()+" by     "+this.getHeight());
   for (int row=0; row < this.getHeight(); row++) // gives the number of rows
   {
     for (int col=0; col < this.getWidth(); col++)// gives the number of columns
     {
       Pixel pix = this.getPixel(col,row);        
       System.out.print(pix.getRed()+" "+pix.getGreen()+" "+pix.getBlue()+" ");
     } // end of inner loop
     System.out.print("\n"); //added line break to end of line.
   }// end of outer loop
} // end of method
```

Comment: It would be _much_ better to use `System.out.println()` instead -- mostly because that's literally what it's meant to do.

Comment: Yes, although someone else has already _made_ an answer with that solution. Therefore i felt it best to leave mine as an alternative as it has many applications others reading might find a future use for.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

Put this after your col loop:

System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

See this page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html